# Tricky: In CSS and HTML, how to make a sub DIV go under the container if the container has a z-index of 0?

Tags: css

This might be a more advanced CSS question about `z-index`:

You can see it in http://jsfiddle.net/cPdge/6/

Using the current Firefox, Chrome, Safari, or IE 9, you should see the blue DIV on top of the parent DIV.

How do we make the blue box go under the parent DIV?  **Note: If the z-index for the parent DIV is removed, then the blue DIV will go under it, but what if the z-index is not removed and remain as `0`?**  Why is a `z-index` of `0` or no `z-index` specified make a difference? Usually, none specified is the same as `0`.

The code in that page is:

```
    <div id="box1">
        some content
        <div id="subbox1">blue
        </div>
        <div id="subbox2">orange
        </div>
    </div>​
```

and CSS:

```
#box1 { width: 600px; height: 400px; border: 6px dashed orange; 
  position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px; background: #ffe; z-index: 0 }

#subbox1 { width: 300px; height: 200px; border: 6px dashed orange; 
  position: absolute; top: 310px; left: 100px; background: #eff; z-index: -10000 }

#subbox2 { width: 300px; height: 200px; border: 6px dashed orange; 
  position: absolute; top: 210px; left: 200px; background: #fc9; z-index: 2000 }
```

Comment: _"Usually, none specified is the same as `0`."_ No, [unspecified means `auto`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index), which is different from `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your negative `z-index` would work if `box1` were not positioned, otherwise the subboxes are in a child [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context), and cannot be positioned under the parent box.

http://jsfiddle.net/cPdge/7/

> Why is a z-index of 0 or no z-index specified make a difference?

The answer to this in on the document I linked to: to create a new stacking context, the element must be both positioned and have a declared `z-index` (or have `opacity` less than 1, which is a little weird...).

Comment: good to know of stacking context for the first time... you know why that if the parent has no z-index specified, then the blue DIV will go under it?

Comment: Because then they would both be in the same stacking context, so they can be layered in relation to each other. It's the combination of `z-index: n` and `position:absolute` on both levels that is creating two different contexts on your code.